# Broacasting message in LAN in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, networking, udp

I am broadcasting the message in a LAN using UDP protocol on 192.168.1.255 address and my app has a receiving socket too
 It causes me to listen my own broadcasted packet too,
How to get rid of this problem? 
Thanks !!

Comment: you can't.   just filter it based on source.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Broadcasts are delivered to *all* listening hosts in the range, which includes yours. Your two options are

1. Don't have the sender listen on that port.
2. Have the sender mark or track the packet somehow and ignore packets it sent itself.

Comment: its compulsion to listen on the same port and can't either mark :/

Comment: @Talib So track them. But how exactly "can't" you mark the packets? Most applications need some sort of sender identity, and if nothing else you have the sending (your own) IP.

Comment: @talib use IP and port for source.  that way you can run multiple copies of the app on the same machine.